# why devise powered model's after_create hook does not work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using devise 3.0.0 with rails 4. In user model I have:

```
  after_create do |user|
    user.avatars.create! active: true
  end
```

I tested it in the console(rails c)

```
u = User.new email: 'sss@sasa.com', password: 'password', password_confirmation: 'password', confirmed_at: Time.now
```

And when I test u.valid?, it returns true. but if I do u.save! There will be this exception:

```
irb(main):004:0> u.save!
   (1.3ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'sss@sasa.com' LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("confirmed_at", "created_at", "email", "encrypted_password", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["confirmed_at", Tue, 06 Aug 2013 01:56:24 CST +08:00], ["created_at", Tue, 06 Aug 2013 01:56:33 CST +08:00], ["email", "sss@sasa.com"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$10$prbSSAErr7fpJcCu/z.G8.PCvgGfn/n4RZfRk1AEiDKx1GNB6r8uq"], ["updated_at", Tue, 06 Aug 2013 01:56:33 CST +08:00]]
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 13]]
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: translation missing: zh-CN.activerecord.errors.messages.record_invalid
    from /Users/jx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails-4.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/validations.rb:57:in `save!'
    from /Users/jx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails-4.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:41:in `save!'
    from /Users/jx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails-4.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:275:in `block in save!'
    from /Users/jx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails-4.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:326:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
    from /Users/jx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails-4.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:200:in `transaction'
    from /Users/jx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails-4.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:209:in `transaction'
    from /Users/jx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails-4.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:323:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
    from /Users/jx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails-4.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:275:in `save!'
    from /Users/jx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails-4.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:37:in `insert_record'
    from /Users/jx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails-4.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:463:in `block (2 levels) in create_record'
    from /Users/jx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails-4.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:367:in `add_to_target'
    from /Users/jx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails-4.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:461:in `block in create_record'
    from /Users/jx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails-4.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:152:in `block in transaction'
    from /Users/jx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails-4.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:200:in `transaction'
    from /Users/jx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails-4.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:209:in `transaction'
    from /Users/jx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails-4.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:151:in `transaction'
... 14 levels...
    from /Users/jx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails-4.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/validations.rb:57:in `save!'
    from /Users/jx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails-4.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:41:in `save!'
    from /Users/jx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails-4.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:275:in `block in save!'
    from /Users/jx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails-4.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:326:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
    from /Users/jx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails-4.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:202:in `block in transaction'
    from /Users/jx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails-4.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:210:in `within_new_transaction'
    from /Users/jx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails-4.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:202:in `transaction'
    from /Users/jx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails-4.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:209:in `transaction'
    from /Users/jx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails-4.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:323:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
    from /Users/jx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails-4.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:275:in `save!'
    from (irb):4
    from /Users/jx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails-4.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /Users/jx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails-4.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/jx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails-4.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:64:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
```

And u.errors show no error:

```
irb(main):006:0> u.errors
=> #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fd6ee613178 @base=#<User id: nil, confirmed_at: "2013-08-05 17:56:24", confirmation_sent_at: nil, confirmation_token: nil, email: "sss@sasa.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$prbSSAErr7fpJcCu/z.G8.PCvgGfn/n4RZfRk1AEiDKx...", reset_password_sent_at: nil, reset_password_token: nil, remember_created_at: nil, current_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, sign_in_count: 0, created_at: "2013-08-05 17:56:33", updated_at: "2013-08-05 17:56:33">, @messages={}>
```

What's wrong with after_create call back? Thanks!

Comment: you have some translation missing:  zh-CN.activerecord.errors.messages.record_invalid

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You lead me find the problem: avatar in call back is invalid. If you answer my question, I will accept it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have some translation missing: zh-CN.activerecord.errors.messages.record_invalid,
 just to get the accepted answer :D

Thx